# Layout Manager For Web Based Interfaces

Tags: javascript, css, layout

I am working on an application with a rather complex layout structure. I plan on using Kendo UI for my JavaScript component needs. My challenge right now is, layout though. I'm not sure if there is a CSS framework that's recommended or a JavaScript framework. To be honest, I'm not even sure which options are available and which are recommended.

Ideally, I need a grid, docking, and possibly even wrapping capabilities. The first two (grid and docking) are definites. The wrapping is a nice to have. Can anybody make any recommendations based on these requirements?

Thank you

Comment: I would use CSS Grids / CSS Reset in the YUI 3 Library. The CSS Grids seem to only have a few issues in early versions of IE. Other than that, it will work. www.yuilibrary.com. You may even want to look at their JS Framework. It is not as heavy (unless you use all of their modules) as frameworks such as jQuery... (IMO) If not YUI, there is a "Formee" framework that has grids & auto-padding that I use from time to time.